# "Extended properties" component in the connection string

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string

My connection string `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=<FILENAME>;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=no;\";`
works on my computer but does not work on the server. I thought it might be because Excel/OLEDB versions are different. Could you tell me:

1. How to determine the provider and what needs to be installed.
2. How to determine the right value for Extended Properties? does `8.0` correspond to Excel version? If I have Excel 11 (2003) only, is `8.0`? Is specifying Excel version mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link to help you determine the current release of jet.40 that is installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239114)

Maybe try:

```
<%
  set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
  conn.Open "c:/MyDB.mdb"

  response.write(conn.Provider)

  conn.close
%>
```

The Excel 8.0 source database type string is used to specify both Microsoft Excel 8.0 and 9.0 workbooks, see [this msdn link for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140022%28v=office.10%29.aspx#adoproperties_extendedsettings)

Comment: My problem was due to an 64bit vs. 32bit issue. Excel 8.0 seems to be fine if any Excel of version 8.0 or higher is installed.

Comment: The way I deal with which provider to use is based on the file name, i.e. .xls jet 4.0 for excel 8 is fine, but with .xlsx I use Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; i.e. excel 12.0